# Java 17 migration inaccessible object for XStream

Tags: java, xstream, java-17

We recently tried to upgrade java version of our project to java 17.
project is using XStream. x-stream.github.io
according to the official page of XStream, java 17 is having trouble using it and it occurs inaccessible object exception. the recommendation of xstream official page is to use JVM argument: `--add-opens` coming with some options appending to declare module
this recommendation is also mentioned in java 17 migration guide of Oracle.
I've never used JVM arguments before and the question is how to use it and more importantly what is the exact format of this argument and options? what is the appending part of this argument and how should I use it? and what exactly do they mean by 'module' in the appending?
(I've tried --add-opens lonely and without options but at the end fails and asks me to declare the module)

Comment: The format is: `--add-opens <module>/<package>=<target-module>(,<target-module>)*`. For example, `--add-opens foo/com.example=bar` would open the `com.example` package in the `foo` module to the `bar` module.

Comment: If you're not familiar with what modules are, then I recommend reading [Understanding Java 9 Modules](https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html) for a brief introduction.